# So this is an answer in the shape of a rhetorical question?

Tags: discussion

As background:
I agree that bad answers are still answers.
I agree that answers in the shape of a rhetorical question are still answers.
I agree that a bad answer in the shape of an unexplained rhetorical question is still an answer.
I agree that a bad answer should not be flagged as "not an answer".
I have several times in the past helped authors of answers in rhetorical question shape to rephrase, in order to avoid exactly the misunderstanding I seem to have had here.

So, just to put my mind at rest, this

> did you use enctype="multipart/form-data" for the form?

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57639225/7733418)

is such an answer and it is just that nobody, not even users with deep insights into the technicality here, has found this to be a useful answer in now more than a day, while three users (not counting me) found this not to be an answer.

That would mean that the
"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" is an appropriate note on my declined flag.

Yes, I admit that I ask because I feel a little miffed about getting a flag declined with such a "tactful" message when the flagged answer requires such an amount of insight to be spotted as an answer.
Even if the single-keyword answer IS actually an ingenious solution provided by a low rep new user, I find rejecting the flag questionable. It is quite reasonable to judge that this is much more likely a clarification question by somebody yet lacking the privilege to ask in a comment. I am not expecting the answer to be deleted, but just my flag to be tolerated as honestly and seriously considered (i.e. helpful), even if lacking a little insight.

Somebody with more php/laravel/etc. knowledge than me, please confirm and explain that/how it is an answer and so far from a question comment that a flag is not helpful.
Then I will accept it and sleep easy...

Comment: FWIW I read it the same way you do...

Comment: For those who cannot see deleted answers, it read, in its entirety "did you use enctype="multipart/form-data" for the form?"

Comment: Don't take it personally. Maybe a mod made an honest mistake? Maybe the answer is an answer, but plain wrong? If you are convinced the flag response is an error, just flag again with a custom explanation. No need for Meta involvement.

Comment: I had a flag on this too that was declined, and I was wondering why. These types of answers have been deleted several times in the past too, It'd be nice to get some clarity here.

Comment: @jpp You are right, mods are humans; but I know I am a human, too. I try to avoid assuming that everybody else makes mistakes instead of me. Yes, it helps my pride that people seem to agree with me, but I also want somebody else to point out my mistake. The more convinced I am, the more important that is.

Comment: That's the issue when you have such lenient rules in regard of answers. Everything that can help to answer the question is qualified as an answer, such a question that might give a hint into the correct direction can be an answer as well. So it is up to the mod (or queue reviewers) if they think that hint is helpful or not.

Comment: IMO someone with no subject-matter expertise at all would likely see that post as a request for information/clarification, rather than a suggested solution.

Comment: @CertainPerformance As they should, but other might see it as hint into the correct direction and that's the issue. Posts like that should never be considered an answer.

Comment: Wait, are clarification requests really answers now?

Comment: I didn’t decline it but probably would have. It looks like a rhetorical question (e.g. a question that is its own answer). If not that, then an answer where the answerer wants to show that that’s what they think it is, but it could not be that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You seem to know how it could be an answer. Could you please sketch how mentioning that single technical thing can be an answer? That would help me accept that I was wrong, even if it is a bad answer or even bad and wrong.

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply that at all. It looks like it *could* be a (poor, badly-worded) answer to a completely different question, but here, even if you squint, I think it's pretty hard to see how it could even be an attempt to address the problem OP is asking about - but then again, I don't have any domain expertise here

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry for misinterpreting you. I still hope for an explanation, it would be my shortest path to peace.

Comment: Remember that mods aren't experts in everything, so for something to qualify as "not an answer" it should *clearly* not be an attempt to answer the question even without any knowledge of the technology.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Henke What I am asking is "So this is an answer in the shape of a rhetorical question?" with "this" referring to the linked post and "being an answer in the shape of a rhetorical question" implying that flagging it as "not an answer" is inappropriate, with the consequence that a corresponding flag is correctly declined. Of course I ask because I am unsatisfied with the decision. I admit that this is repeating/summarising my question post. I.e. I do not see how you can be unclear about what I am asking. Could you elaborate what is puzzling you?