# Why was my flag to a rude/abusive answer declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, rude-or-abusive

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57674134) answer as rude or abusive because:

- The username was garbage (jooooooooooooooooooooooo)
- The answer consisted of:

  > `code`jooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

  which makes it flaggable as per [What are the "spam" and "rude or abusive" (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035), emphasis mine:

  > Abuse of the system or community is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. This includes posts by new users that contain no useful content at all – i.e. **gibberish posts**

So, why was this declined?

Related incidents:

- [I flagged this non English answer as NAA, why was my flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388907)
- [So this is an answer in the shape of a rhetorical question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388862)
- [Why was my flag on a seemingly link-only answer declined by a moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388894)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I disagree that these flags should have been declined. The post was abusive of the site. It was the only post made by a troll account. The account was destroyed by a moderator, with the reason:

> This user was created to post spam or nonsense and has no other positive participation

In my view if an account deserves to be destroyed, it means so does the content of that user, as we only destroy accounts of people who abuse/troll or spam the site. For context, mods have the power to delete or destroy accounts. Sock puppet accounts would be deleted, as they may have contributed decent content despite the intent of being created to upvote a master account.

I undeleted the post and flag deleted it via a rude/abusive flag for the sake of consistency.

I cannot retrospectively un-decline these flags or I would. ***But they have been disputed.***

Noteworthy, posts deleted by rude flags are not eligible for audit queues, spam deleted posts are.

---

***Bah*** Having a few weeks off has changed my brain to jelly. I was able to dispute the declined rude/abusive flags, but now I'm unable to re-delete the post as rude, so just deleted it.

Comment: @double-beep yes I thought I could, but there's some type of change with the interface. I'm not sure if I've uninstalled a script or what I'm missing. I'll ask Shog. I am supposed to be on a break from the site (So I had uninstalled a lot of scripts.) , but feel the need to step in a little.

Comment: @double-beep I spoke to a CM. I think it can only work if the flag has been marked as helpful and then cleared, it becomes disputed.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks :) I'm trying not to handle flags, as I'm uber busy IRL. I just thought if I actually don't read the site it might be a totally different concern by the time I get back... and reading leads to talking and you know the rest :D

Comment: @double-beep ikr! I am missing a script I'm sure. It's 5.49am here, I'll ping Rob for when he wakes up :D

Comment: @double-beep done!

Comment: related guidance at MSE: [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773) "The problem folks have with these is that they see the pile of nonsense and *try to extract meaning from it...* This is an utter waste of time. **There is no meaning to the post!** ...pick the flag that speaks to you. I'm partial to "rude or abusive", because enough of them *immediately* delete and lock the post, which is handy in those rare scenarios where someone's flooding the site with a *lot* of these..."

Comment: Upvote for second revision alone :). If I could, I would update twice for the first.